# I can't resize/partition my disk using gparted

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install ubuntu alongside windows 10 but when i run gparted i cannot shrink either of the existing partitions. They appear to be full but in reality there is about 30GB free.

[image]

Comment: They are not full. They are broken. Look at the exclamation mark next to them (!), it will tell you something informative on what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

When you shut down Windows 8, 8.1 and 10 it's is not really shut down. It's a hybrid between shut down and hibernation. Filesystem on Windows is not really closed too. To get rid of those exclamation marks RESTART Windows and then boot into Linux. Then GParted should be able to do partition resizing.